# AWS ios sdk :getting error while uploading data to s3 ( nw_endpoint_flow_prepare_output_frames Failed to use 1 frames, marking as failed)

Tags: amazon-s3

nw_endpoint_flow_prepare_output_frames [3.1 54.231.169.28:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Failed to use 1 frames, marking as failed
2017-04-10 10:26:54.471091 AWSIntegration[1373:23681] [] nw_endpoint_handler_add_write_request [3.1 54.231.169.28:443 failed socket-flow (satisfied)] cannot accept write requests
2017-04-10 10:26:54.471638 AWSIntegration[1373:23391] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [22] Invalid argument

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It is probably an issue with your IAM.

For me it was the resource name from AWS guide that was the problem. It was missing the * at the end:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example.bucket.name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```